# Maxima CAS , Statistic Formula with Maxima

Tags: statistics, maxima-software

I am working on my graduation project which study sport players' performance.

I have collected the data and finished all the surveys but then I am stuck at using the following formula to calculate the values that I want. I was told that maxima could help me to   figure the answer but I just have no idea. I've never deal with two summations.

[image: adjusting wining percentage]

What can I do with it? I have the k,n and i value. how can I start? or is there any other software can help with it easily like excel? or can somebody give me an example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In maxima you can write quite complex programs in it's language, just like you would in a regular language like C. The main difference is that the variables contain expressions, not numerical values. A CAS might help in simplifying partial expressions. The term in the internal sum looks like amenable to simplification, and perhaps parts can be moved out of the internal sum. You might even get lucky, and have the sum have a closed form (check out the Zeilberger package; but the factorials at half integers might complicate things).